# Google-cloud-messaging/gcm push notification not delivered to client

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a Server-Client communication via Push from Server to Client. Since the Client is an Android device, I'm using Google Cloud Messaging to fulfill pushing a message from server to android device. I followed this  [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/)

**Current status:** The Client get's the Registry ID from GCM. So the client - GCM communication should be fine. The Server get's the following message while trying to push the message to gcm :

> 2015-01-20T23:31:24.289+0100|Information: Response Code : 200
>   2015-01-20T23:31:24.290+0100|Information: {"multicast_id":534481856434...,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1421793086402018%64d756d9f9fd7ecd"}]}
>   2015-01-20T23:31:24.296+0100|Information: com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.coyote.PECoyoteResponse$PECoyoteWriter@49...

It seems like the connection between client - gcm is working. But the gcm doesn't forward the message to my client.

My gcm project is also showing just 2 requests and over 2000 errors. I don't know that much about push notification to handle this issue, maybe somebody could help me.

Here's my code

**Client** MainActivity

```
// ... some other imports
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

   GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
   String regid;
   String PROJECT_NUMBER = pn;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       getRegId();
   }

   public void getRegId() {
       new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               String msg = "";

               try {

                   if (gcm == null) {
                       gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                   }

                   regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
                   msg = "Device registered, registration ID = " + regid;

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   msg = "Error: " + e.getMessage();
               }
               Log.d("Systemablauf", "MainActivity getRegId() " + msg);

               return msg;
           }

       }.execute(null, null, null);
   }

}
```

**Client** MessageHandler

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {
    String msg;
    private Handler handler;

    public GcmMessageHandler(String name) {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        msg = extras.getString("title");
        showToast();
        Log.d("Systemablauf", "Received: (" + messageType + ") " + extras.getString("title"));

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void showToast() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Client** BroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

        Log.d("Systemablauf", "onReceive()");
    }
```

}

**Client** Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="thesis.com.example.clientsync"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="thesis.com.example.clientsync.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="thesis.com.example.clientsync.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver 
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category 
                    android:name="thesis.com.example.clientsync" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
          android:name="service.MainService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Server** Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/ServerServlet")
public class ServerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public ServerServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                   
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sendNotification();
    }

    private void sendNotification() {

        System.out.println("Sending POST to GCM");
        String apiKey = "AIzaSyA0pOZf13cZzqQHrWBZfFE9XFMHA5ftiAo";

        Content content = createContent();
        POST2GCM.post(apiKey, content);
    }

    private static Content createContent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Content c = new Content();

        c.addRegId("APA91bFrSX_mGLzLUf2Va6...");
        c.createData("Test Title", "Test Message");

        return c;
    }   
}
```

**Server** Post

```
public class POST2GCM {

    public static void post(String apiKex, Content content) {

        String apiKey = "AIzaSyA0pO...";

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key = " + apiKey);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            Gson gsonMapper = new GsonBuilder().create();
            DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.writeBytes(gsonMapper.toJson(content));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL: " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                response.append(inputLine);

            in.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Server** Content

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Content implements Serializable {

    private List<String> registration_ids;
    private Map<String, String> data;

    public void addRegId (String regId) {
        if (registration_ids == null)
            registration_ids = new LinkedList<String>();
        registration_ids.add(regId);
    }

    public void createData (String title, String message) {
        if (data == null) 
            data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        data.put("title", title);
        data.put("message", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to follow good tutorial to study GCM, please refer to here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd8bIkE29U4 I tried, and it works perfect

Comment: I think you are sending GCM on hardcoded device Id i.e. c.addRegId("APA91bFrSX_mGLzLUf2Va6...");

Comment: The shown version is just for testing. At first i request the register id for my android device, copy this register id and paste it into my code `c.addRegId(deviceRegID)`. I just dotted the regid for security. So the hard coding shouldn't be the problem since i want adding the regid via http post message from android device to client in the future.